# PySpark SubQuery: Accessing outer query column is not allowed

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to re-write a SQL query into PySpark. Below is the SQL query:

```sql
SELECT 
cs.Environment, 
cs.AccountCode,  
MIN(cs.StartDate) AS StartDate,         
MIN(cs.FinalDate) AS FinalDate, 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 ItemCode 
    FROM [dbo].[Contracts] 
    WHERE 
        Environment = cs.Environment 
        AND AccountCode = cs.AccountCode 
        AND ContractType = 'C'      
        AND LinePackage = 1             
        AND InflowOutflow = 'Inflow'    
        AND EventDate <= GETDATE()      
    ORDER BY EventDate 
) AS Package

FROM [dbo].[Contracts] cs
WHERE 
    cs.ContractType = 'C'
    AND cs.LinePackage  = 1
GROUP BY 
    cs.Environment, 
    cs.AccountCode
```

My PySpark code is this one:

```py
df = spark.sql(
    """select cs.environment, cs.accountcode, 
              min(cs.startdatets) as startdate, min(cs.finaldatets) as finaldate,
              (select a.itemcode 
               from firstcomm as a 
               where a.environment = cs.environment and a.accountcode = cs.accountcode and a.contracttype = 'c' and a.eventdate <= current_date() 
               order by a.eventdate limit 1) as package 
        from firstcomm cs where cs.contracttype = 'c' and cs.linepackage  = 1 
        group by cs.environment, cs.accountcode""")
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
AnalysisException: Accessing outer query column is not allowed in:
LocalLimit 1
+- Project [itemcode#3641]
   +- Sort [eventdate#3629 ASC NULLS FIRST], true
      +- Project [itemcode#3641, eventdate#3629]
         +- Filter ((((environment#3628 = outer(environment#3628)) && (accountcode#3622 = outer(accountcode#3622))) && (contracttype#3626 = c)) && (((linepackage#3644 = 1) && (inflowoutflow#3637 = inflow)) && (eventdate#3629 <= current_date(Some(Zulu)))))
            +- SubqueryAlias a
```

By the way, I'm using Spark 2.2.1 which I believe that sub queries are supported

Any ideas how to fix this issue ? or how should I re-write query to get the desired result ?

Comment: Did you try to limit them?

Comment: I think you can change your inner select into a join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you comfortable using the pyspark dataframe api?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# get the top item code for each environment/account code
package_df = contracts.filter((F.col("ContractType") == 'C') & (F.col("LinePackage") == 1) & (F.col("InflowOutflow") == "Inflow") & (F.col("EventDate") <= GETDATE())).orderBy("EventDate")

package_df = package_df.withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("Environment", "AccountCode").orderBy(F.col("ItemCode").desc())

package_df = package_df.filter(F.col("row_number") == 1).drop("row_number")

# aggregate over your contracts table and join the top item code
contracts_df = contracts.filter((F.col("ContractType") == 'C') & (F.col("AccountCode") == 1))

contracts_df = contracts_df.groupBy("Environment", "AccountCode").agg(F.min("StartDate").alias("StartDate"), F.min("FinalDate").alias("FinalDate"))

# join to get the top item code
output_df = contracts_df.join(package_df, ["Environment", "AccountCode"])
```

I used window functions to get the top item code per key, then joined that in to your aggregated original dataframe.

Comment: But you didnt help by using .sql(). I need to keep in sql query.